# Hide all highlights

Tags: formatting, highlighting

TLDR: How to automatically hide all `hl` elements in the PDF?

I have a latex document where I use the `soul` package to include highlighted text in my pdf, e.g. `\hl{test}`. These are only meant for me and when I send the document to others I would like to hide all of them without deleting them. For example, by adding

```latex
\hide{hl}
```

to the beginning of the document. I would just need to comment this in or out depending on whether my document should contain my yellow remarks.

Does such a command exist or do I have to manually comment out each line with `%`?

Comment: `\renewcommand\hl[1]{#1}` ? or `\renewcommand\hl[1]{}` if you want to lose the text as well as the highlighting

Comment: Big thanks! The second one is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `hl` for example `\renewcommand\hl[1]{#1}` or `\renewcommand\hl[1]{}` if you want to lose the text as well as the highlighting.

You might want

```
\renewcommand\hl[1]{\ignorespaces}
```

so that

```
aaa \hl{this} bbb
```

doesn't get an effective double space between aaa and bbb.